# Populating docbook table from xml file

Tags: xml, xslt, populate, docbook

## Question

I am looking reasonable way to populate docbook tables from xml files. Goal is to have docbook file which contains some kind of minimal reference to data needed. When the docbook file is processed to final publication this reference should be substituted with data retrieved from xml file.

## Specific Example

Below is specific example to illustrate this further. It is pretty detailed because my first try to ask this question was too vague.

**source-document.docbook**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<article xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" version="5.0" xml:lang="en">
    <info><title/></info>
    <table><title/><tgroup cols="2"><tbody>
        <row>
            <entry>good in comparative</entry>
            <entry>
                <phrase role="populateme">
                    <phrase>good</phrase>
                    <phrase>ADJ COMP</phrase>
                </phrase>
            </entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <entry>good in superlative</entry>
            <entry>
                <phrase role="populateme">
                    <phrase>good</phrase>
                    <phrase>ADJ SUPL</phrase>
                </phrase>
            </entry>
        </row>
    </tbody></tgroup></table>
</article>
```

**source-database.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<database>
    <row>
        <cell>good</cell>
        <cell>ADJ POST</cell>
        <cell>good</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>better</cell>
        <cell>ADJ COMP</cell>
        <cell>good</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>best</cell>
        <cell>ADJ SUPL</cell>
        <cell>good</cell>
    </row>
</database>
```

**processing**

Makefile contains recipe to produce `publication.pdf` from `source-document.docbook` and `source-database.xml`. (Currently my tools of choice are xsltproc and fop, but others can be suggested.)

**publication.pdf**

Normal docbook prepared pdf publication with following substitutions:

```
<phrase role="populateme">
    <phrase>good</phrase>
    <phrase>ADJ COMP</phrase>
</phrase>
```

Above produces `better` instead of `goodADJ COMP`.

```
<phrase role="populateme">
    <phrase>good</phrase>
    <phrase>ADJ SUPL</phrase>
</phrase>
```

Above produces `best` instead of `goodADJ SUPL`.

**final remark**

```
<phrase role="populateme"><phrase>ref</phrase><phrase>ref2</phrase></phrase>
```

Above "syntax" is very cumbersome but, I could not yet think any better that is valid docbook.

## Preliminary thoughts about solution

**XInclude tags**

- pros: xml technique
- cons: bad support of xpointer, solution would be probably be cumbersome if at all possible

**xslt preprocessing transformation**

- pros: xml technique
- cons: xslt is quite confusing, further this could be impossible to achieve with xslt?

**python preprocessing script**

- pros: possibly simplest solution to achieve this?
- cons: inability to achieve this with xml's own mechanisms

**something other?**

Any input about which way I should take this and why is welcome. As well as full code examples etc.

Comment: Is "xml file" the input to the process and "docbook file" the desired output? What is the "target document"? What is "tag based syntax? Please clarify.

Comment: @mzjn "docbook file" and "xml file" are the 'source' files. They should produce "target document" (pdf file in my case) after processed trough toolchain (xsltproc and fop at the moment) invoked from makefile. Toolchain can contain preprocessing before actual docbook tools (or after if you need). Target document should have above substitutions taken place. By tag based syntax I mean something like "<populateme><arg>good</arg><arg>ADJ SUPL</arg></populateme>" which is proper XML. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an XSLT stylesheet:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
            exclude-result-prefixes="db"
            version="1.0">

  <xsl:variable name="database" select="document('source-database.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="db:entry[db:phrase[@role='populateme']]">

    <xsl:element name="entry" namespace="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
      <xsl:value-of select="$database//row[cell[3] = current()/db:phrase/db:phrase[1]
                            and cell[2] = current()/db:phrase/db:phrase[2]]/cell[1]"/>
    </xsl:element>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The stylesheet performs a lookup in **source-database.xml**. When it is applied to **source-document.docbook**, the following result document is produced:

```
<article xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" version="5.0" xml:lang="en">
  <info><title/></info>
  <table><title/>
  <tgroup cols="2">
    <tbody>

      <row>
        <entry>good in comparative</entry>
        <entry>better</entry>
      </row>

      <row>
        <entry>good in superlative</entry>
        <entry>best</entry>
      </row>

    </tbody>
  </tgroup>
  </table>
</article>
```

This document (let's call it **publication.docbook**) you can then turn into a PDF (**publication.pdf**).

I think it is something like this that you are looking for. Am I right?

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. I was hoping that there is some way to achieve this reasonably elegantly. Thank you.